# How can I switch to a different ESLint style guide?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, eslint, standardjs

I started a new **Vue** project with **vue-cli** and Webpack and configured **ESLint** to *Airbnb's* style guide.

How can I change this choice to a *Standard* style? I am getting really tired of the surplus in commas and semicolons, and want to give it [Standard JS](https://standardjs.com/) a try.

I am working alone at this project right now, so do not worry about team complains :)

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard

Comment: @Prasheel I use vim for configuration and Sublime Text 3 for Vue. Although this question is more related to the command line or the file system, I think.

Comment: @samayo so i can just run the commands given in that link on top of my already ESLint configured app? If not, I do not know where to start with that repo...

Comment: Install the library and modify your eslint file with the example given. I haven't tried it but I will. You may find some info here also https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/73

Comment: Found a way to disable ESLint for the moment: in **config/index.js**, set `useEslint: true` to false. At least no Airbnb Style Guide, thanks @samayo!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but some of the rules are actually okay, so try to use it without that empty/tab/space nonesense

Comment: Have you succeeded changing the coding style to StandardJS?

Comment: @user7637745 Yes, although this should be for me a one use case. Not need to do this again in the future, I hope...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install [StandardJS](https://standardjs.com/) via `npm install standard --save-dev`.

Then run [**through the rules**](https://standardjs.com/rules.html) just to quickly get a feel of it.

Finally, create a **script in your package.json** to run StandardJS, when you need it:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "check": "standard"
  }
}
```

...then you can run it via `npm run check`

---

To provide a quick way to yourself to fix most coding style typos, add a **fix script to your package.json**:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "check": "standard",
    "fix": "standard --fix"
  }
}
```

...and run via `npm run fix`

---

To get a more **nicer representation** of coding style errors, install **snazzy** via `npm install snazzy --save-dev`, then modify your package.json like so:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "check": "standard --verbose | snazzy",
    "fix": "standard --fix"
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a different solution for my particular case, but I think this is a well constructed answer for my question.